# Cloud 9 IDE - Web Server running but not displaying in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cloud9-ide

I have a rails application running in Cloud 9 IDE. When I run using the command line

```
rails s -b $IP -p $PORT
```

Running this command displays the console log

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.2.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.6.3 codename Protein Powder)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:8080, CTRL+C to stop
```

But when I try to open the URL in browser, it says "No application seems to be running here!", but at the same time, I try using

```
curl  http://0.0.0.0:8080
```

this is working properly.

I tried restarting the IDE but still the same, check the C9 status all operational.

Comment: what url are you trying to open? and what's your environment name + folder

i.e: your ide url is : https://ide.c9.io/username/environment_name

so your server should be accessible at:
https://environment_name-username.c9.io

Comment: @AlexandreVoyer - yes right, I am using the correct URL. When I tried running the workspace in debug mode its working fine, but without debug does not work. The only difference between yesterday (when all was working fine) and today is a git pull.

Now I am trying to create a new workspace and see if works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved, not sure what was wrong, since I did not do anything, I started the IDE today and it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and got it working again without waiting. Background processes were interfering. Killed all processes with:

```
killall5 -9
```

In the terminal before restarting the app.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Lam good to know about this command, killall -9 for c9, I just did a restart of my container and it started working.

Comment: Probably a quirk in c9's backend. I tried restarting my container a couple times but the error didn't go away - had to kill the processes manually

Answer (score -1):

You need to click on "run project". And then click on "CWD" to set the working directory for the server.

Reference:
https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/run-an-application